# format convert date variable using SAS

Tags: date, format, sas

I want to convert a character date variable (categorical) in the format 9/12/1990, 10/1/1990, etc. into this format: 09/12/1990, 10/01/1990, etc. (mmddyy10.) using SAS.

```
format date_new mmddyy10.;
date_new =input(trim(VAR1),mmddyy10.);
```

The code is not working.

Comment: It is respected in the SO community that the one who asks question should display some prior research or attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Is the original variable character or formatted numeric?

Comment: @AlexA. it's an original variable char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
data new;
    set old;

    /* Parse character date components */
    array dt[*] month day year;
    do i = 1 to 3;
        dt[i] = input(scan(var1, i, "/"), best.);
    end;

    /* Recontruct date */
    date_new = mdy(month, day, year);

    format date_new mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Documentation links:

- [`mdy`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bo5thbfrcab1n1menkqxq2suiv.htm)
- [`scan`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0jshdjy2z9zdzn1h7k90u99lyq6.htm)
- [SAS dates](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm)
- [Arrays](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1i7zlvukj8arhn1ihivqz9mot9m.htm)